# Test if exact string appears in a Pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pattern-matching

In a Pandas df['Column'] (i.e. a pandas Series)

If I use

```
df['company_name'].str.contains('ABC').any()
```

I will get 'True' if an entry is "ABC"

But it will also return a (false positive) "True" if some other entry in the Series is "ABC PTY LTD"

I only want to match if there is an entry that is exactly "ABC"

I've checked about 50 similar questions but none answer this one.

I tried a Regex

```
rec_df['recruiters'].str.match( r'^ABC$').any()
```

It works but the problem is I want to pass the 'ABC' part into the regex as a variable and I can't work out how.

Any help for a NooB who trying to learn please?

Any solution that would match a record with exactly 'ABC' and not a longer string like 'ABC Pty Ltd' and not a substring like 'AB" would be idea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do

```
df['company_name'].eq('ABC').any() #(df['company_name']=='ABC').any()
```

Comment: Thankyou! I was reading the str.contains part of the API and didn't the the .eq option 
I am very grateful

Comment: Similarly, I need that a search for 'ABC' in 'ABC Pty Ltd' results True and in ''ABCPty Ltd' results False. That is, the result must be True only for whole strings. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Wen for the answer. I also worked out the Regex approach in case anyone needs it.

```
company_name = 'ABC'

item = r'^' + company_name + '$' 

df[‘company’].str.match(item).any()
```